# What is the Big Oh gonna be for this algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0, data-structures, big-o

what are the best case analysis and the worst case analysis for this peace of code?! it's getting a little complicated. help pleaseeee! are we gonna have different Big oh's depending on different inputs? or the big oh's gonna be the same for best case and worst case?

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i =1,j,k;
while(i<=n)
{
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(j%3==0)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=(n/2);k++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }
        else if(j%3==1)
        {
            k=j;
            while(k>=1)
            {
                Console.Write("@");
                k--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(k=1;k<=(j%3);k++)
            {
                Console.Write("$");
            }
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: you need to format it correctly first.

Comment: The lack of indentation makes reading it an  `O(n^3)` operation.

Comment: The braces don't match..

Comment: Still doesn't match..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a class assignment?  I have a feeling you're asking us to do your homework for you.

The short answer is that the algorithm is O(n^3).

The value of n is read from the console.

The outer loop is i = 1 .. n (i is only ever incremented in the loop, i.e. no steps are skipped).

The second loop is j = 1 .. i (j is only ever incremented in its loop, i.e. no steps are skipped).

The innermost loop, at least in the case where (j % 3 == 0) is k = 1 .. n / 2.

So there are ~n^3 steps required to implement this algorithm.

The fact that j goes from 1 .. i means that, on average, j = 1 .. n/2, making the i/j loops require (1 / 2) * n^2 steps, which is still O(n^2).

The fact that the innnermost loop takes n / 2 steps only in the case where (j % 3 == 0) means that it takes, on average, (1 / 3) * (n / 2) steps, or (1 / 6) * n steps.

Combined with the outermost two loops that's (1 / 12) * n^3 steps, which is an O(n^3) algorithm.